# How to cast countDistinct divided by countDistinct to Double using Querydsl

Tags: mysql, jpa, querydsl

I'm querying multiple fields with Querydsl JPA (4.1.4), it's a dynamic API that based on parameters I generate the query.

When I select metric as field.avg() it returns Double, when I select field.count() it returns Long, which is fine, but when my expression has a division of two Longs it returns a Long value, even though the value returnd by DB is a floating point value.

Is there a way to tell Querydsl that the value should be retrieved as double? I already tried to use `.doubleValue()` and `.castToNum(Double.class)` but on MySQL it returns an invalid cast exception.

Sample code:

```
NumberExpression metric = field1.countDistinct().divide(field2.countDistinct());
List<Tuple> tuples = query.select(key, metric)...;
tuples.forEach(tuple -> tuple.get(1, Number.class));
```

I also tried this without success, it still returns Long:

```
Expressions.numberTemplate(Double.class, "{0} / {1}", field1.countDistinct(), field2.countDistinct());
```

**SOLUTION**:

```
field1.countDistinct().doubleValue().divide(field2.countDistinct())
```

throws

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'double precision) as col_2_0_...
```

but using floatValue works

```
field1.countDistinct().floatValue().divide(field2.countDistinct())
```

Comment: although `field1.countDistinct().divide(field2.countDistinct()).doubleValue()` throws

`Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'double precision) as col_2_0_`

`field1.countDistinct().divide(field2.countDistinct()).floatValue()` works fine!